# Django + Crispy Forms + BS3 Layout Issues

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, layout, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to adjust layout of my django-crispy-forms form.  The issue I'm seeing is that the rendering will not honor the bootstrap layout scaffolding.  As shown in the image below, large gaps are left between the label and field and attempts to change the label_class and/or field_class make any difference.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

[Screenshot showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHrfX.png)

**HTML Template:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Tools - Home{% endblock %}

{% block contextmenu %}
    <a href="checklists">View Statistics</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Form:**
class NewChecklist(forms.Form):

```
name = forms.CharField(
    label='Name:',
    required=True,
    max_length=50)

description = forms.CharField(
    label = 'Description:',
    widget = forms.Textarea(),
    required=False,
)

question = forms.CharField(
    label = 'Question:'
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NewChecklist, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-1'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-11'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'name',
        'description',
        'question',
        FormActions(
            Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class="btn-primary"),
            Submit('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class="btn-white"),
        )
    )
```

**View:**

```
def new_checklist(request):
    form = NewChecklist()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'new_checklist.html', context)
```